# Mint 18.1 thinks SSL keys are Apple Keynote presentations?

Tags: linux-mint, mime-types, thunar

In older versions, files ending in .key were correctly identified as SSL keys and had a bank safe icon and opened with a certificate program.

After updating to Mint 18.1, they now have Powerpoint icons and try to open with Open Office. The `Kind` field in Thunar reads, "Apple Keynote 5 Presentation".

How do I fix this? I know I can change the "open with" but it's the type detection that's wrong, not the program it opens with.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does the problem lies in the mime database, specifically the file: /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml

To fix:

Remove entry  from file /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml

Run:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

This will leave the *.key file as default binary, then follow this process with the proper XML descriptor.

[Add new file extension to existing (MIME) type](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360975/add-new-file-extension-to-existing-mime-type)