# Add new file extension to existing (MIME) type

Tags: files, mime-types, file-manager

In Nemo some "twig" files appear with the text icon whilst some appear with a web icon.  I want all files with a "twig" extension to appear in Nemo like "html" files e.g. with a web icon.  So I edited `/etc/mime.types` adding the "twig" extension to the html entry:

```
text/html                   html htm shtml twig
```

And then updated the MIME database using:

```
sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

However it did not work, the twig files still have mixed icons.

I am running Linux Mint version 18.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *freedesktop*'s [unified system](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/latest/ar01s02.html) to define a new association.
Write a new source xml file e.g.

```
~/.local/share/mime/packages/text-twig.xml
```

with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
  <mime-type type="text/html">
    <comment>twig template files</comment>
    <glob pattern="*.twig"/>
  </mime-type>
 </mime-info>
```

then update your mime database

```
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
```

and you're all set.

---

The above will alter `*.twig` files mime type for your current user. For a global change follow the same procedure replacing all occurrences of `~/.local` with `/usr`

Comment: Is it possible to get a different icon rather than a "text file" icon in Nemo through this method?

Comment: Yes.  I have type="text/twig" and I am getting a text icon.  Although this is another question: can I have a unique (custom) icon for the twig types?

Comment: @tyebillion - yes, see link in my comment above (which sends you to another comment of mine on another question of yours...)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177760/where-does-nautilus-get-its-file-type-description other than what you've already said this talks about changing the Nautilus source code which sounds a bit drastic.

Comment: There are 2 answers in the link I just referenced above not to mention other further links.